# Difference in rc.local and lxde autostart

Tags: raspberry-pi, startup

I have created a python script with GUI and I want to be able to run it at start up once the Raspberry Pi boots. I placed my script in the rc.local but the GUI does not appear at start up. But when I placed it in the autostart it does. Can somebody explain what is the difference of using those? Why also does the autostart need to be edited as a user and not as a root?

Here is the path of those files I edited. /etc/rc.local and ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart